# ¿Cómo mandar un formulario con Ajax Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario en `html` el cual quiero enviar por medio de `post` a un archivo para que haga una actualización en la base de datos con esos datos (valga la redundancia) que llegan por el `post`, solo que no tengo idea cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo, sí pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería, dejo el formulario en `HTML` y el archivo `PHP`

`HTML`

```
<form action="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarInser" onsubmit="return validarCampos()" name="formRegistro" method="POST">
    <div class='container justify-content-center shadow p-5 mb-1 mt-n1 bg-white rounded' style= "width: 800px">            
        <div id="errores" class="alert-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-g align-content-centerroup row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" id="fecha" name="fecha">
            </div>
            <label for="sede" class="col-form-label">Sede:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" id="sede" name="sede" >
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar sede</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($sedes); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$sedes[$i]['id_sede']}'>{$sedes[$i]['sede']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>                 
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <div id="mascara" onclick="empleadoIsEmpty()"></div>
            </div>
            <label for="asistencia" class="col-form-label">Asistencia:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="asistencia" name="asistencia"> 
                        <option value="0">Seleccionar asistencia</option>
                        <?php
                            for($i=0; $i < count($asistencias); $i++){
                                echo "<option value='{$asistencias[$i]['id_asistencia']}'>{$asistencias[$i]['siglas']}</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                </select>
            </div>           
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="justify-content-center">                
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4 btn-md" style="width: 150px" type="submit">Registrar</button>            
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md" role="button" style="width: 150px" href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos" >Cancelar</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" onclick="setTimeout('llenarEmpleados()', 1)" type="reset">Limpiar</button>            
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`PHP` donde recibo el `post`

```
public function guardarInser(){

    $controlAsis = new ControlAsistencia();                    
    $controlAsis->fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $controlAsis->empleado = $_POST["empleado"];
    $controlAsis->asistencia = $_POST["asistencia"];     
    $controlAsis->administrador = $_SESSION["usuario"]["id_admin"];        
    $res = $controlAsis->insertarControl();
    if($res){
        $msg = "Se ha insertado correctamente";
    }else{
        $msg = "No se ha podido insertar";
    }        
}
```

Dejo una petición que anteriormente he hecho en Ajax pero no sé sí se haga de la misma forma con el formulario

`AJAX y JQUERY`

```
function llenarEmpleados(){
    var sede = $("#sede").val();
    var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
    var parametros = {
        'sede' : sede,
        'fecha' : fecha            
    };

    if(sede != 0 && fecha != ""){
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=llenarEmpleados',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response){
                $("#empleado").html(response);
                console.log(response);
                $("#empleado").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#empleado").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Anteriormente lo estaba haciendo de la forma simple, que es redirigiendo al archivo y que de ahí lo mande lo devuelva con la respuesta y que la imprima en pantalla y demás, pero es maluco ya que el archivo queda en el enlace, y ya he acomodado eso de manera de que no se vea así, pero ahora prefiero hacerlo con jquery y ajax, que es mucho más fácil y los resultados son mucho mejores
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Haz intentado hacer algo del ajax? Lo quieres hacer en JavaScript nativo o en jQuery? ... adicional creo que tu pregunta puede ser tomada como basada en opiniones y podría terminar cerrada, te recomiendo cambies el contexto

Comment: Pues he hecho otras peticiones con ajax, ya agrego el codigo

Comment: Ok, trataré de responderte de manera detallada

Comment: No espero menos de usted, maestro

Comment: Creo que me excedí un poquito en la respuesta, ojalá te sirva bro!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero que debes saber al enviar los datos de un `form` por `AJAX` es que los atributos `action` y `method` ya no nos servirán de nada, podrás quitarlos sin problema alguno.

Luego de esto, para ejecutar el evento que va a desencadenar el `AJAX` no necesitas precisamente ejecutar el evento `submit` del `form`, podrías también añadir un evento `click` al botón de envío. En caso de que desees utilizar el evento `submit` del `form` entonces tendrás que utilizar un `e.preventDefault();` para anular su comportamiento por defecto.

```
<form onsubmit="return validarCampos()" name="formRegistro">
    <div class='container justify-content-center shadow p-5 mb-1 mt-n1 bg-white rounded' style= "width: 800px">            
        <div id="errores" class="alert-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-g align-content-centerroup row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" id="fecha" name="fecha">
            </div>
            <label for="sede" class="col-form-label">Sede:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" id="sede" name="sede" >
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar sede</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($sedes); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$sedes[$i]['id_sede']}'>{$sedes[$i]['sede']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>                 
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <div id="mascara" onclick="empleadoIsEmpty()"></div>
            </div>
            <label for="asistencia" class="col-form-label">Asistencia:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="asistencia" name="asistencia"> 
                        <option value="0">Seleccionar asistencia</option>
                        <?php
                            for($i=0; $i < count($asistencias); $i++){
                                echo "<option value='{$asistencias[$i]['id_asistencia']}'>{$asistencias[$i]['siglas']}</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                </select>
            </div>           
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="justify-content-center">                
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4 btn-md" style="width: 150px" type="button">Registrar</button>            
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md" role="button" style="width: 150px" href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos" >Cancelar</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" onclick="setTimeout('llenarEmpleados()', 1)" type="reset">Limpiar</button>            
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

En el código de tu formulario he retirado los atributos `action` y `method` del `form`, también he cambiado el tipo del botón registrar de un `submit` a un `button` para así evitar que se ejecute el evento `submit` del `form`.

Puedo ver que tienes una validación de campos al ejecutar el `submit` del `form`, ese código de validación puedes pasarlo a la nueva función que se va a desencadenar con el evento `click` al botón registrar.

En cuanto a tu forma de envío veo que utilizas esta forma:

```
var sede = $("#sede").val();
var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
var parametros = {
    'sede' : sede,
    'fecha' : fecha            
};
```

Esta forma es correcta, los datos se envían correctamente pero imagina que tienes un formulario grande con unos 50 campos en el...¿Capturarías el valor de cada campo uno por uno? Obviamente no, por lo cual la mejor forma es usar el método [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) de `jQuery`, éste método lo que hace es crear una cadena de texto `URL` codificada por la serialización de los valores del formulario, lo podrás observar en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$("#btnEnvio").click(function(){
  var datos = $("#myForm").serialize();
  
  console.log(datos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <input name="nombre">
  <input name="apellidos">
  <input name="mensaje">
  
  <button type="button" id="btnEnvio">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Entonces una vez serializados los datos puedes proceder con el envío:

```
var datos = $("#tuFormulario").serialize();

$.ajax({
    data: datos,
    url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarInser',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response){
        // Código de éxito
    }
});
```

En tu **PHP** puedes recibirlos de la misma manera en la que ya lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Uy, como sea tengo que entender ésta respuesta, eres el mejor bro!! Para aclarar la parte de Ajax que coloqué ahí es para hacer otra cosa, pero pues, es el metodo que sé hacer, whatever, muchas gracias hermano!!

Comment: @DaxTter77 si no entendés algo preguntame que con gusto te respondo men, igual ajax es un método un poco amplio por ejm para el envío de imgs habría que hacer otros cambios y etc etc, la buena bro!

Comment: Tranquilo, está completamente entendible, pero como yo soy amante de probar de todo, voy a tomar en cuenta todo lo que me dijiste, y quiero preguntarte algo, qué pasaría sí yo en el `action` lo pongo de esta manera `action='javascript: metodoParaEnviarElForm()' funciona también?`

Comment: @DaxTter77 no debería de funcionar ya que el atributo action especifica a donde se enviarán los datos del form, no está hecho para ejecutar funciones

Comment: Y sí te digo que me ha funcionado? xd

Comment: Dejame lo intento y te cuento

Comment: Andá al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), creamos una sala para nosotros y me cuentas por allá, los comentarios no deben usarse para extender una conversación

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    $.post( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
      $("#server-results").html( response );//este puede ser un div para que muestres el mensaje del resultado o cualquier otra cosa
    });
});
```